# Why is my L-cross type function not showing me the correct results?

Tags: clustering, ripley-k, spatstat

Hi I'm trying to spatially analyse two point patterns in relation to each other: macrophage cells and tumour cells. The images I have generated coordinates from shows that the macrophages group towards the tumour cells but my graph from the imhomogenous L-cross type function shows the opposite. I don't know where I'm going wrong here. Attached is my results graph.

this is my code:

```
#this lets me wipe R's memory
rm(list=ls())

#this allows me to load the spatstat package
library(spatstat)

#this is me loading in my tumour data and plotting it
tumour.data <- read.table(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
summary(tumour.data)

#this is me turning my table into  matrix
tumour.matrix <- data.matrix(tumour.data)

#ok it is now time for me to do the exact same for my macrophage data; load it
macrophage.data <- read.table(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
summary(macrophage.data)

#turn it into a matrix
macrophage.matrix <- data.matrix(macrophage.data)

#now i need to make my window
win <- owin(xrange=c(0,10000), yrange=c(0,10000), poly=NULL, mask=NULL,
             unitname=NULL, xy=NULL)
plot(win)

#i need to convert my matrix into a point pattern so that spatstat can read it
p_tumour <- ppp(x = tumour.data$X, y = tumour.data$Y, window = win)

#convert my matrix into a point pattern so that spatstat can read it
p_macrophage <- ppp(x = macrophage.data$X, y = macrophage.data$Y, window = win)

#gotta combine these ppps now
comb <- superimpose("cancer" = p_tumour, "macrophage" = p_macrophage)

#let's define my r value for the radii that i want to look at
radii <- seq(0, 3, by=0.1)

#use cross-type l function
results <- Lcross.inhom(comb, "cancer", "macrophage", r = radii, correction = "Ripley")

#and the final touch
plot(results)
```

[image: l cross type function for my data suggesting that the data are dispersed from each other]

Comment: Without the data it’s not possible to reproduce your results.